# Performance of ISNULL and COALESCE with a constant as second value

Tags: sql-server

I have seen in some projects to use COALESCE like this:

```
COALESCE( [MaterialType], 'ROH')
```

This expression COALESCE([field], constant) is equivalent to use the ISNULL() function, except for the nullability of both expressions.

My question is:

Is the performance of COALESCE([field], constant) better than ISNULL()?

Thank you

Comment: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/performance-isnull-vs-coalesce.aspx  (isNull faster barely) Now note: Coalesce will allow N values to be compared while isNull is limited to just the 2 unless you nest functions.   I personally stick with coalesce as it's more RDBMS independent; and I'll take a slight performance hit for that and flexibility of not nesting nulls.  Also note the resulting datatype may vary: isNull takes the type of first input, coalesce looks at all entries and usees the type of highest precedent. http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull

Comment: While these two are often used interchangeability they are different.  But based on This specific usecase, isNull should function slightly faster based on adam_macanic's article.  Should be noted that the SQL server version makes a difference.  and in comments adam illustrates coalesce is faster in 2008.   long story short: performance tune later (if needed); get correct results first and you'll likely find other areas to tune to get better performance first.

Comment: So Both functions have a quite similar performance but COALESCE is compatible with more RDBMS.